# Why DistributedCache is caching all files directly into the root of the tmp storage dir in Hadoop 2

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2, distributed-cache

I'm migrating hadoop 1.0.4 codes into a Hadoop 2.3 platform, and met with a weird behavior change of DistributedCache:

In hadoop 1, if we want to cache a file at `/user/foo/file/bar/name.avro`, the DistributedCache will copy this file into a local cache folder, and create the same sub directories accordingly. So the file is stored at `/[ROOT_OF_TMP_CACHE_DIR]/user/foo/file/bar/name.avro`.

Now the same codes in Hadoop 2 will put the file directly in the root folder without creating any sub directories. So now the cached file is stored at: `/[ROOT_OF_TMP_CACHE_DIR]/name.avro`.

This will cause name conflicts if we are caching multiple files especially when file names are like `part-r-00000.avro`.

Of course, applying a link and renaming the cached file into a unique name can be one way to solve this problem; but more generally, creating unique names seem to be trivial in many cases, especially when needs to guarantee unique names across different mappers/reducers. I'm wondering if there any other ways to change this behavior, such as creating a folder within the tmp dir or maybe tune a mapreduce configuration parameter?

One way I tried is try to make the URI into "path#path", so we are linking to ourselves, but seem to get the following exception:

```
14-10-2014 16:05:41 PDT admm_train INFO - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Resource name must be relative
14-10-2014 16:05:41 PDT admm_train INFO -   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.parseDistributedCacheArtifacts(MRApps.java:489)
14-10-2014 16:05:41 PDT admm_train INFO -   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.setupDistributedCache(MRApps.java:430)
14-10-2014 16:05:41 PDT admm_train INFO -   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.createApplicationSubmissionContext(YARNRunner.java:455)
14-10-2014 16:05:41 PDT admm_train INFO -   at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:283)
14-10-2014 16:05:41 PDT admm_train INFO -   at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:432)
```

Answer (score 1):

This bug is due to a change of internal behavior of DistributedCache in Hadoop 1 and 2.

In Hadoop 1, a to-be-cached file will be stored at a local tmp directory retaining all its previous path structure. For example, if we are caching hdfs:///foo/bar/file1 in Hadoop1, it will be stored at /[some tmp path]/foo/bar/file1.

In Hadoop 2, DistributeCache will peel out the path structure, to store hdfs:///foo/bar/file1, it will directly store it at /[some tmp path]/file1.

Also if you are using symblink names, Hadoop 2 will rename the file to the link name while Hadoop 1 will not. This results in some compatibility conflicts while switching from Hadoop 1 to Hadoop 2.

An easy solution to this is always use symlink name, and then access the file via the name so that even they are stored differently, we can still access them in the same fashion.